# Hide some tick numbers in a TikZ/PGF axis environment

Tags: pgfplots, axis

I want to plot a function using the axis environment. The code for the axes so far is

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines = middle,
axis line style = {Stealth-Stealth, very thick},
xmin = -.1, xmax = 1.1, ymin = -4.5, ymax = 5.5,
xtick distance = 1/8,
ytick distance = 1,
xlabel = $\omega$,
ylabel = $f_1(\omega)$,
grid = major,
grid style = {thin, densely dotted, black!20}]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Unfortunately, I do not know how to include the corresponding picture properly. The problem with the code above is that the xticklabels are rounded to two digits, i.e. they are rounded to 0.13, 0.25, 0.38, etc., which might be confusing. So I would like to delete the labels 0.13,0.25,... while keeping the xticklabel 1. I know that I could delete all the xticklabels by using

```
xticklabel = \empty
```

but is there also a way of specifying that I only want some of the xticklabels?

Comment: Does using `xtick distance = 1/4` not do what you desire? If you want to specify them manually you could use `xticklabels={,,,0.25,,0.5,,0.75,,1},`.

Comment: I need the ticks every 1/8-th, since I want to include step functions which are constant on those intervals. But thank you very much, this solves the problem!

Answer (score 1):

You could use minor ticks:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines = middle,
axis line style = {Stealth-Stealth, very thick},
xmin = -.1, xmax = 1.1, ymin = -4.5, ymax = 5.5,
xtick distance = 1,% <- changed
minor x tick num=7,% <- added
ytick distance = 1,
xlabel = $\omega$,
ylabel = $f_1(\omega)$,
grid = both,% <- changed
grid style = {thin, densely dotted, black!20}]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with `xtick distance=1/2` and `minor x tick num=3`:

[image]

`xtick distance=1/4` and `minor x tick num=1`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have drawn various kinds of functions. In my experience, except some weird functions (the Weirstrass function,...), the command `\draw plot` of TikZ is enough, and flexible.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5,x=10cm]
\draw[thin, densely dotted, black!20] 
(-.1,-4.5) grid[xstep=.1] (1.1,5.5);
\draw[-stealth] (-.1,0)--(1.1,0) node[above]{$\omega$};
\draw[-stealth] (0,-4.5)--(0,5.5) node[right]{$f_1(\omega)$};
\foreach \j in {-4,...,-1,1,2,...,5}
\draw (0,\j) node[left=1mm]{$\j$}
--+(0:1.5mm)--+(180:1.5mm);
\draw (1,0) node[below=.5mm]{$1$}
--+(90:1.5mm)--+(-90:1.5mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```